# Crossthread operation not valid... - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, multithreading

I am using vb.net, and in my program I get this 'crossthread operation not valid' error when I run my backgroundworker that will make this textbox enabled true. My main sub will first turn the enabled to false, and when the backgroundworker runs it will turn it back true then exit. Why does it give me an error? FYI: There is more code to this but I don't want to make it any more confusing...

Here is the stack trace:

```
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Enabled(Boolean value)
   at Helium.Form1.BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Kevin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Helium\Helium\Form1.vb:line 167
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

and here is the exact error message:

```
{"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'mainText' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."}
```

Can someone please help me out!

Thanks,

KEvin

Comment: I would think the error message was pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The purpose of the `BackgroundWorker` class is to perform work on a **non-GUI** thread while the GUI remains responsive. Unless you set `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `false` (which you shouldn't do), or use `Invoke` as suggested in the other answers (which I also wouldn't recommend), you're going to get an illegal cross-thread operation exception.

If you want GUI-related "stuff" to happen **while** your `BackgroundWorker` is running, I'd generally recommend using the `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` method and attaching an appropriate handler to the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event. If you want something on the GUI to happen once the `BackgroundWorker` is **finished**, then simply attach your handler to update the GUI to the `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event.

Comment: +1. Using the `backgroundworker.reportprogress` helped me in updating my gui while the thread is on the run.

Answer (score 15):

Better way to this in VB.NET is to use a `Extension` it makes very nice looking code for cross-threading GUI Control Calls.

Just add this line of code to any Module you have.

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Sub Invoke(ByVal control As Control, ByVal action As Action)
    If control.InvokeRequired Then
        control.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() action()), Nothing)
    Else
        action.Invoke()
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you can write Cross-Thread Control code that's only 1 line long for any control call.

Like this, lets say you want to clear a ComboBox and it's called from threads or without threads you can just use do this now

```
cboServerList.Invoke(Sub() cboServerList.Items.Clear())
```

Want to add something after you clear it?

```
cboServerList.Invoke(Sub() cboServerList.Items.Add("Hello World"))
```

Answer (score 14):

Where exactly do you set the `Enabled` property? If you do it within the `DoWork` event handler, this code is running on a different thread than the button was created on, which should give the exception that you experience. To get around this, you should use `BeginInvoke`. For convenience it could be wrapped into a method, like so:

```
Private Sub SetControlEnabled(ByVal ctl As Control, ByVal enabled As Boolean)
    If ctl.InvokeRequired Then
        ctl.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of Control, Boolean)(AddressOf SetControlEnabled), ctl, enabled)
    Else
        ctl.Enabled = enabled
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you can safely call that method to enable or disable any control from any thread:

```
SetControlEnabled(someButton, False)
```

Answer (score 14):

Type the following code in the `Form1_Load` (or whatever your form is) sub:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

It fixes all problems with blocked cross-thread operations.

Comment: Note that this answer is *bad*, as explained in [Is it safe just to set CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false to avoid cross threading errors during debugging?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345091/is-it-safe-just-to-set-checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls-to-false-to-avoid-cross-t). **Please do not use it and instead fix the issues with your code (i.e, create proper delegates).**

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly set a control's property that is on the UI thread from another thread. It can be done though, here is an example from msdn.

```
Private Sub SetText(ByVal [text] As String)

    ' InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the'
    ' calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.'
    ' If these threads are different, it returns true.'
    If Me.textBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
    Else
        Me.textBox1.Text = [text]
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: so where should I put the textbox1.enabled = true part?

Answer (score 0):

Your Form_Load () pls write below code part. All your problems will be solved.

```
'## crossed-thread parts will not be controlled by this option...

System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use AutomationPeer.

For example below code calls Execute button when I press F5 key. Similarly if you want a thread or Background worker to call an event or function you can use Automation Peer.  In your case instead of button (Which I used here) you can use text box with its appropriate property to invoke.

```
'Button name=btnExecute

'Imports System.Windows.Automation.Peers

'Imports System.Windows.Automation.Provider

If e.Key = Key.F5 Then

   Dim peer As New ButtonAutomationPeer(btnExecute)

   Dim invokeProv As IInvokeProvider = TryCast(peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke), IInvokeProvider)

   invokeProv.Invoke()

End If
```

Regards
RV

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat way to have your cake and eat it too! Or in other words, here's a way for you to **write UI interactive code inside your `BackgroundWorker`** and not encounter a cross-thread operation. I threw this together one day for a project, buyer beware!

```vb
' Init background worker
Dim _BGWorker As BackgroundWorker

' Your Windows Form's _Load event handler:
Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Just for this example, we're newing up the _BGWorker here
    _BGWorker = New BackgroundWorker()
    _BGWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
End Sub

' Magical UI Action Handling ProgressChanged Event Handler Thing (v24.4.550-alpha9) ™ ©
Private Sub _BGWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles _BGWorker.ProgressChanged
    ' Take the UserState object and cast to an Action delegate type
    Dim uiAction As Action = CType(e.UserState, Action)

    ' Check if an action was passed
    If uiAction IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Run it if so!
        uiAction()
    End If
End Sub

' Standard DoWork handler for BackroundWorker
Private Sub _BGWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles _BGWorker.DoWork
    '...your background worker code...

    ' EXAMPLE:
    '
    ' Me.Text = "Background worker is (trying to) change form title! :-O"
    '
    ' This line would normally fail with an exception when written directly in the DoWork
    ' handler of a BackgroundWorker. Exception you would see is:
    '   System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'FormName'
    '   accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

    ' BUT...

    ' If we write something like this:

    _BGWorker.ReportProgress(-1, New Action(
    Sub()
        '...and put that line inside this action:
        Me.Text = "Background worker is changing form title! :-O"

        ' Then NO PROBLEM! UI-interactive code MAGIC!

        ' Well, it's not magic... This works because this code is not executed here immediately.
        ' It is an Action Delegate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-7.0
        ' You can write ANY UI-interactive code inside blocks like this in your BackgroundWorkers
        ' and they will all execute on the main thread, because the Action delegate is being 
        ' shipped to the ProgressChanged event handler on the main Form thread.

        'TODO: Add your other UI code...

    End Sub))

    ' Now simply repeat the above section every time you wish write UI-interactive
    ' code in your BG workers! SHAZAM!

    '...your background worker code...
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

Comment: Please add some additional explanation.