# Is it safe just to set CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false to avoid cross threading errors during debugging?

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms

In WinForms applications, is it safe just to set [CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls(v=vs.110).aspx) to FALSE to avoid cross threading errors during debugging?

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Comment: You might think you can get away with it, but just bite the bullet and FIX THE DAMN CODE. ;)

Comment: :D i just want to know the consequences of not fixing the code

Comment: You're not avoiding threading errors, just the detection of them.

Comment: @orange Note that the C# tag isn't appropiate as the question is about .NET with Winforms and not specifically C#. The syntax doesn't matter and the only difference between VB.NET and C# (both .NET) being the semicolon. As the question applies to both languages and you kept the C# tag, you might as well add the VB.NET tag as well...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, that's not safe.  The Winforms code that checks for threading mistakes is **very** important, the trouble that causes is extremely hard to diagnose.  The biggest problem is that it doesn't cause consistent failure, your app will misbehave randomly and deadlock or crash only once a month.  Or never at all, until you make a minor change.  Or only on a particular user's machine, you'll blame the user instead of your code.

The only reason the CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls property exists in the first place is to keep .NET 2.0 and up compatible with buggy .NET 1.x programs where this threading safety test was not performed.  Backward compatibility for bugs ;-P

Comment: Hans seems like it would be a good idea to explicitly set this property to true otherwise it will only blow up when testing locally (as its initially assigned the value of `Debugger.IsAttached`)

Comment: It is okayish, but your release build ought to run as fast as possible.