# Thread is not getting called

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am trying to call a thread on a button click event. i dont fell my code is not making any syntax error. but its not working.

```
    Private Sub btnHisStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHisStart.Click
        thrHis = New Thread(AddressOf threadHistorical)
        thrHis.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub threadHistorical()
        'code
    End Sub
```

Comment: have you debugged it?

Comment: Can you show the code in the `threadHistorical` method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this line and check it

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

Comment: you can run into race conditions and deadlocks if you are not careful. You could have multiple threads trying to update the same control at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. this is what making the exception

Comment: I am trying to make number of threads on the same form. so may be they might be overlapped. anyway my issue solved

Comment: -1 Setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` is a bad hack. Although it may seem like it has solved the issue, it will come back to bite you. You should use `Control.Invoke` instead

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345091/c-sharp-checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls for more info on CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls