# Wait for thread to finish without blocking UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am writing `winForm` app which have to listem `SerialPort` and print the data into multi line `textbox` in real time.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SCPListener
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            GetAvailablePortNames();
            panel1.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f44147");
            cbDefaultValue();
        }

        String[] PortNames;
        bool conn = true;
        String data;
        public string datetime;
        Form2 frm = new Form2();

        void GetAvailablePortNames()
        {
            PortNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(PortNames);
        }


        void RefreshAvailablePortNames()
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            PortNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(PortNames);
        }
        public string getDataTime()
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            string date = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            return date;
        }
        public void GetData()
        {
            string date = getDataTime();
            data = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            textBox1.AppendText("[" + date + "] " + "Received: " + data + "\r\n");
        }
        public void cbDefaultValue()
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox5.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox4.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (comboBox1.Text == "" || comboBox2.Text == "" || comboBox3.Text == "" || comboBox4.Text == "" || comboBox5.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please port settings", "Incorrect port settings", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
                    string date = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                    serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);
                    switch (comboBox3.Text)
                    {
                        case "5":
                            serialPort1.DataBits = 5;
                            break;
                        case "6":
                            serialPort1.DataBits = 6;
                            break;
                        case "7":
                            serialPort1.DataBits = 7;
                            break;
                        case "8":
                            serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                            break;
                        default:
                            serialPort1.DataBits = 5;
                            break;
                    }
                    switch (comboBox4.Text)
                    {
                        case "None":
                            serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
                            break;
                        case "Odd":
                            serialPort1.Parity = Parity.Odd;
                            break;
                        case "Even":
                            serialPort1.Parity = Parity.Even;
                            break;
                        case "Mark":
                            serialPort1.Parity = Parity.Mark;
                            break;
                        case "Space":
                            serialPort1.Parity = Parity.Space;
                            break;
                    }
                    switch (comboBox5.Text)
                    {
                        case "One":
                            serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                            break;
                        case "Two":
                            serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.Two;
                            break;
                        case "OnePointFive":
                            serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.OnePointFive;
                            break;
                    }
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    string CurrentPornName = comboBox1.Text;
                    label7.Text = "Opened " + CurrentPornName;
                    panel1.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#42f477");
                    comboBox1.Enabled = false;
                    comboBox2.Enabled = false;
                    comboBox3.Enabled = false;
                    comboBox4.Enabled = false;
                    comboBox5.Enabled = false;
                    //button5.Enabled = false;
                    //button6.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unauthorized Acces","Access Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else if (ex is System.IO.IOException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please plug in your device", "IO Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f44147");
            string CurrentPornName = comboBox1.Text;
            label7.Text = "Closed " + CurrentPornName; ;
            serialPort1.Close();
            comboBox1.Enabled = true;
            comboBox2.Enabled = true;
            comboBox3.Enabled = true;
            comboBox4.Enabled = true;
            comboBox5.Enabled = true;
            //button5.Enabled = true;
            //button6.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshAvailablePortNames();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            Thread thread = new Thread(start: ()=>
            {
                try
                {
                    datetime = getDataTime();
                    string date = getDataTime();
                    startListening:
                    if (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                        datetime = getDataTime();
                        data = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                        textBox2.AppendText("[" + datetime + "] " + "Received: " + data + "\r\n");
                    }
                    else
                        textBox2.AppendText("[" + datetime + "] " + "Error: There is no data to read" + "\r\n");
                    if (conn)
                        goto startListening;
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
                    string date = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                    if (ex is TimeoutException)
                    {
                        textBox1.AppendText("[" + date + "] " + "Timuot Exception" + "\r\n");
                    }
                    else if (ex is InvalidOperationException)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Plese check settings", "Error: Invalid Operation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    else if (ex is System.IO.IOException)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Port opened, but device unpluged..", "IO Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }

                }
            });
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn = false;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
                try
                {
                    datetime = getDataTime();
                    string date = getDataTime();
                    startListening:
                    if (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                        datetime = getDataTime();
                        data = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                        textBox2.AppendText("[" + datetime + "] " + "Received: " + data + "\r\n");
                    }
                    else
                        textBox2.AppendText("[" + datetime + "] " + "Error: There is no data to read" + "\r\n");
                    if (conn)
                        goto startListening;
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
                    string date = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                    if (ex is TimeoutException)
                    {
                        textBox1.AppendText("[" + date + "] " + "Timuot Exception" + "\r\n");
                    }
                    else if (ex is InvalidOperationException)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Plese check settings", "Error: Invalid Operation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    else if (ex is System.IO.IOException)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Port opened, but device unpluged..", "IO Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }

                }

        }
    }
}
```

About Code:

```
comboBox1 -> where the Ports are listed
comboBox2 -> where the Baud Rates options are listed
comboBox3 -> where the Stop Bits options are listed
comboBox4 -> where the Data Bits options are listed
comboBox5 -> where the Parity options are listed
button1 -> to connect chosen port
button2 -> to disconnect port
button3 -> to start listening and print data into textBox in real time
button4 -> to stop listening
button5 -> refresh available ports
panel1-> to identify port is connected or not (if connected it is green if it is not connected it is red)
```

So, what i want to do is that when I click the stop button (`button4`), program have to stop listening. I am trying to achieve this result using `backgroundWorker` .
Using this code when i try to listen port (clicking start button `button3` there is opening the small error window and tell please check settings (so it catching `InvalidOperationException` according to my code); If I wont use `backgoundWorker` and also remove `try{...} cath{...}`  program start do display the received data from port but blocking the UI. Any ideas will be very helpful.

Comment: You'd better rename your variables (combo boxes and buttons) first :)

Comment: You are aware you can rename your controls and so give them *descriptive* names? That would remove the need for you to provide a *key* to your code.

Comment: @zcui93 They doesn't have any sense in this case :).

Comment: Suggest you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first. Please value other's time.

Comment: Naming conventions aside, in short you should use a worker thread and decide how you want to end it.  You can gracefully shutdown the thread, or just abort it and ignore the exception.  That's up to you.  There are a lot of articles and answers on gracefully shutting down a thread. 
On a side note, why use if(con) goto vs just wrapping it in a while(con)? :)

Answer (score 1):

button4_click needs to call backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync() instead of setting a bool.  With BackgroundWorkers, you need to specify that you want them to end and then check for it, setting and checking an outside bool will not work.  The try block in your backgroundWorker1_DoWork() method should look like the following.  Keep in mind, it is easier for you and others to help you if you rename your variables (either done in the UI or by right clicking the variable and selecting 'Rename').  Another note before the code, it is almost never ok to use 'goto', there is almost always a better option (a while loop in this case).

```
datetime = getDataTime();
string date = getDataTime();
while (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
{
    if (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
    {
        datetime = getDataTime();
        data = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        textBox2.AppendText($"[{datetime}] Received: {data}\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        textBox2.AppendText($"[{datetime}] Error: There is no data to read\r\n");
    }
}
```

Edit to say: This should get you started, you will also want to check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387676/updating-the-gui-from-background-worker) to access your UI from backgroundWorker1, the problem is your UI is on one thread and your BackgroundWorker on another, threads do not work well together without some complimenting code

Comment: Thanks, I have trid this code but now there is cross-threading error.