# "Cross-thread operation not valid" - Except, I'm not performing a cross-thread operation. C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've seen a lot of suggestions for resolving this error:

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'pictureBox4' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

The only problem is, my issue doesn't apply to the solutions I've seen.  This is **not** a cross-thread operation.  Here's the code:

```
private void green()
    {
        // declare initial variables 
        int xGreen = 64;

        // Get bitmap from picturebox
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox4.Image;

        // search through each pixel via x, y coordinates, examine and make changes. Dont let values exceed 255 or fall under 0.  
        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
            {
                Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                int myRed = c.R, myGreen = c.G, myBlue = c.B;
                myGreen += xGreen;
                if (myGreen > 255)
                    myGreen = 255;
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, myRed, myGreen, myBlue));
            }

        // assign the new bitmap to the picturebox
        pictureBox4.Image = (Bitmap)bmp;
        pictureBox4.Refresh(); 
    }
```

`pictureBox4.Image` works fine.  `pictureBox4.Refresh()` triggers the incorrect error.  `picturebox4` **is** being used on the form it was created on.

What is causing this error to trigger?  Using `pictureBox4.Refresh()` in other areas of the code works fine.

By the way, I'm been away from this code for a bit, but I do fully plan on updating it to use `lockbits`.

Thank you

Comment: Questions: 1. Which particular line triggers the exception? 2. How are you calling this method?

Comment: The last line pictureBox4.Refresh(); I'm calling it using green();

Comment: And how/where do you call `green()` ?  It's an incomplete question. You do have a thread somewhere.

Comment: @AARRGGHHH: it's not about `green` itself but how do you call `green`. As Henk says, you have a thread somewhere.

Comment: green() is called from a pictureBox click.  
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             green();

Comment: continuing, green() is called from a pictureBox click.  It's called by simply using green(); The pictureBox (pictureBox1) is on the same form as pictureBox4.  

I'm not certain why this question is receiving down votes, perhaps readers are not reading the entire question. This is **not** a duplicate of the many "Cross-thread operation not valid:" questions, this is a question dealing with a control that first works, and then mysteriously generates a "Cross-thread operation not valid:" error,  when there does not appear to be a cross-thread issue.

Comment: Edit the question with this info, comments don't count here. Reading the entire question is not enough now.

Comment: And make sure the entire code path is accurate, don't 'simplify' anything.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to update UI in a non-UI thread. You can dismiss this exception by using below code to change pictureBox4.Refresh() or other similar access code to sth as below:

```
pictureBox4.InvokeIfRequired(() =>
{
    // Do anything you want with the control here
    pictureBox4.Refresh();    
});
```

Comment: _"CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false"_ - That's a dreadful idea.  _[The only reason the CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls property exists in the first place is to keep .NET 2.0 and up compatible with buggy .NET 1.x programs where this threading safety test was not performed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345091/c-sharp-checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls)_

Answer (score 0):

I think you're calling update UI control in non-main thread. 
If so, you can use this.Invoke to ask main thread update control for you.
Something like:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate{pictureBox4.Image = (Bitmap)bmp;
pictureBox4.Refresh();}));
```

Or asynchronous form:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate{pictureBox4.Image = (Bitmap)bmp;
pictureBox4.Refresh();}));
```