# Why VS2010 Express throws unsafe Threading error but command line csc.exe does not?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, csc, visual-studio-2010

Been cogitating over this for a while. There are no Unsafe declarations in the code.

It compiles perfectly from csc but not from the IDE. I got it working in the IDE by changing

```
this.listBox1.Items.Add("example msg. . . ");
```

to:

```
listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Add("example msg . . . ")));
```

and it continues to work from the command line. The thread is started in a different function

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FuncContainingAddToListBox));
        thread.Start();
```

I understand that there are differences in the compilers, and that more can be done with the command line version, but I'm failing to hone in on what in this case... Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Can you give the exact error/exception? It seems more like runtime exception than a compiler error, but you make it sound like a compiler error.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the compiler.  This is a runtime error, you get it in the IDE because you use a debugger.  When you run it from the command line you don't use a debugger.  It is [backwards compatibility for bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13345622/17034).

Comment: @mike z: my bad, I did mean to say it was a runtime error...