# Why isnt my Control class working for WPF with the Forms reference .NET TCP C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, tcp, reference

I am trying to create a super simple TCP / IP Connection between a server and a client.
But it's throwing me this error.

> 'Control' does not contain a definition for
>   'CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls'

See.. I'm using a WPF project to create this even though it was written for WinForms, but it should work just fine since I am adding the Windows.Forms reference right?

```
public void listenerThread()
{
    TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(8080);
    tcpListener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        Socket handlerSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
        if (handlerSocket.Connected)
        {
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false; //This line is throwing me the error.
            lbConnections.Items.Add(handlerSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " connected.");
            lock (this)
            {
                nSockets.Add(handlerSocket);
            }
            ThreadStart thdstHandler = new
            ThreadStart(handlerThread);
            Thread thdHandler = new Thread(thdstHandler);
            thdHandler.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `using System.Windows.Controls;` or write `System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;`.

Comment: But you shouldn't set that property at all: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13345622/1136211

Comment: What I did was removed the `using System.Windows.Controls;` and added `using System.Windows.Forms;`