# Cross-thread issue not resolved despite the usage of Invoke()

Tags: multithreading

My C# app has lots of forms to perform various tasks. To keep things simple, I have a static class `FormsCollection` where the instances of each of the other forms are kept, so that they are shown and hidden from one place.

Now i was getting that classic [debug time "Cross-thread" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345091/is-it-safe-just-to-set-checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls-to-false-to-avoid-cross-t). I tried to fix it the following way:

```
public class FormsCollection : Control // inherited from Control only to be
                                       // able to call "this.Invoke"
{
    public delegate void ShowFormDelegate(Form form);

    public static Main mainForm;
    // and many other forms...

    public void ShowForm(Form form)
    {
        if (form.InvokeRequired)
        {
            ShowFormDelegate delegateFunc = new ShowFormDelegate(ShowForm);
            this.Invoke(delegateFunc, new object[] { form });
        }
        else
        {
            previousForm = currentForm;

            currentForm.Hide();
            currentForm = form;
            currentForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the user/caller forms, i simply make an object of `FormsCollection` and call the `ShowForm` method (almost a 100 such calls):

```
FormsCollection f = new FormsCollection();
f.ShowForm(FormsCollection.mainForm);
```

And after all this ordeal, what i get is that the same error appears at the very same spot as before! What an irony! :)
What am i doing wrong? Please help me out....

Comment: I debugged my app from a different angle and got the following: `Additional information: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.` at the code line: `this.Invoke(delegateFunc, new object[] { form });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got extremely hard-to-find answer to this problem from [this slightly irrelevant page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/449594/Progress-Bars-Threads-Windows-Forms-and-You). Following is the updated code for any struggling programmers looking for a work around to this problem:

```
public void Show(Form nextForm)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(
        new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            PreviousForm.BeginInvoke(
                new Action(() =>
                {
                    PreviousForm = CurrentForm;
                    CurrentForm = nextForm;

                    PreviousForm.Hide();
                    CurrentForm.Show();
                }
            ));
        }
        ));

        thread.Start();
    }
```

This seems to have resolved the cross-thread problem that i was facing despite several work-arounds. It is working as yet without raising any exceptions and I have tested almost all the scenarios of my app going back and forth from form to form.