# TCP/IP Client Connection Issue

Tags: vb.net, tcp, ip

Im having trouble with a tcp client. When the client starts their form they send a client.connect request to me, when i open up my form i accept the incoming request so we are then both connected and it shows connected, but when i close the clients form it still shows we are connected even though we are not.

```
    Dim Listener As New TcpListener(4355)
    Dim Client As New TcpClient
    Dim Message As String

    Private Sub Listen()
    Try
        Listener.Start()


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    MyBase.Load
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    'IP.Text = My.Settings.IP
    Try
        Dim Listening As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listen))
        Listening.Start()


    Catch ex As Exception
        Application.Restart()
    End Try
    Sending1.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    Timer2.Tick
    If Client.Connected = False Then
        Label5.Text = "Disconnected"
        Label5.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Sending1.Enabled = False
        Client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient() 'looping accept request
    End If
    If Client.Connected = True Then
        Label5.Text = "Connected"
        Label5.ForeColor = Color.Green
        Sending1.Enabled = True
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: There is too little code for us to be able to reproduce it or identify any issues. To start with: Where is this code located? In a button? Timer? Thread? Other? Please update your question to include the minimal code required for us to reproduce the problem. For guidelines see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: updated, sorry about that

Comment: I see you are still using `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`. You _**urgently**_ need to get rid of that and do [**proper thread-safe invocation**](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/1913/threading/6235/performing-thread-safe-calls-using-control-invoke) instead. I'm not saying this because that is the best way of doing it, I'm saying this because _**YOU MUST!**_

Comment: Disabling `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is like disabling the airbag in a car. It is there to protect you, but by disabling it you don't know exactly what will happen when you crash - the same goes for your application. Disabling `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` and not doing thread-safe invocation will at some point cause concurrency issues on the UI thread which will seriously break the application flow (at the very least). At this point your application can break in so many ways, and you can never predict what will happen because the behaviour is different every time.

Comment: As for your issue (and _**DO NOT**_ ignore what I just wrote above!): `Listener.AcceptTcpClient()` is a blocking call and will block the UI thread until it receives a connection. Therefore the UI might not have the time to redraw itself before that line is hit, which could be why you never see the label change text. You can confirm this by placing a [**breakpoint**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) on the line and see if it ever reaches it when the other endpoint disconnects. If it does then the UI just needs to redraw itself; if it doesn't you have another issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13345622

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ElseIf`.

```
If Client.Connected = False Then
    Label5.Text = "Disconnected"
    Label5.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Sending1.Enabled = False
    Client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient()

ElseIf Client.Connected = True Then
    Label5.Text = "Connected"
    Label5.ForeColor = Color.Green
    Sending1.Enabled = True
End If
```

Hope that It help :)

Comment: It makes no difference. The OP hasn't given us enough code to be able to identify the issue.