# how to use delegate in multi thread loop

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates

I am trying to populate a combobox with elements quickly. If I iterate through them, the delay is too long for my liking (a few seconds). So after researching options, I'm trying to use a parallel loop to do it async. However, I am getting a cross threading error populating the combo box, so I am trying to use a delegate sub, but vb won't let me saying that "add_item is a type and cannot be used as an expression." My code is below:

```
Parallel.For(0, search_results.Count - 1, Sub(x)
                                              add_item(search_box, search_results(x)(0) & " - " & search_results(x)(1) & " " & search_results(x)(2))
                                          End Sub)


Private Delegate Sub add_item(ByVal sb As ComboBox, ByVal txt As String)

Private Sub update_search_box(ByVal sb As ComboBox, ByVal txt As String)
    If sb.InvokeRequired Then
       sb.Invoke(New add_item(AddressOf update_search_box), New Object() {sb, txt})
    Else
       sb.Items.Add(txt)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The easy and lazy fix is to add `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` to the form's load event and forget abount delegates. This will stop the Cross-threading error.

Comment: Does it help if you do a BeginInvoke on the control instead (i.e., BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() sb.Items.Add(txt) EndSub)

Comment: @BanForFun : That's also the bad and irresponsible fix. In other words: **DON'T DO IT!!** The errors are there to **stop you** from doing something bad. If you disable them you can no longer be sure that the code you've written will work like you intended it to.

Comment: @BanForFun : It's also easier to jump from a cliff rather than having to climb all the way down, though which option do you prefer? My point is that disabling those errors _**is**_ so fatal that you shouldn't even suggest it. Your application _**WILL MOST CERTAINLY**_ do unexpected things at some point.

Comment: @VisualVincent Haha. Yeah you're right. I don't recommend it at all, but at the other hand i have never had a bad experience using it.

Comment: @BanForFun : May so be, but how do you know that for sure? You might never have noticed that something broke just because it was very a tiny incident? The thing about disabling `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is that you can no longer predict when some things should go wrong. The application will literally behave unexpectedly. As [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13345622) puts it: _"it doesn't cause consistent failure, your app will misbehave randomly and deadlock or crash only once a month. Or never at all, until you make a minor change"_.

Comment: Just a small thought - Just before the loop adding the items, have you tried `sb.SuspendLayout` and after adding them, `sb.ResumeLayout`? I suspect, that your ComboBox may be trying to repaint itself after each add. This stops that.

Comment: Instead of mucking around with multi-threading that is

Comment: David, I tried that and it doesn't seem to make much difference. I think it's just the sheer volume. We have millions of people in the database and when you search for a person with a last name of "Smith" you get 94,000+ results. I know that is too much for a combo box, but if I limit it, then it makes the search unusable. You need to be able to  find anyone in the list or it won't work properly. Once you find then you need to select them in the drop down list. The drop down also shows first name and account number so you know exactly which one you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_item` is a delegate which you use to *refer* to your original `update_search_box` method.

You already use the delegate from within the `update_search_box` method itself, so all you need to do is to call the actual method:

```
Parallel.For(0, search_results.Count - 1, Sub(x)
                                              update_search_box(search_box, search_results(x)(0) & " - " & search_results(x)(1) & " " & search_results(x)(2))
                                          End Sub)
```

Comment: I tried that but then the program just hangs. I never get an error and it does not lock up, but it just stops processing at that point and does not go any further.

Comment: @user2721815 : That's because you are updating the UI so often. You'd be better of adding the items in batches. Add them to a list, then take them from that list every _x_ milliseconds and add them to your combo box.

Comment: Vincent, You are correct in your answer. I did need to call the update_search_box routine directly. So this does answer the question, but it doesn't resolve my issue. It still takes way to long using this method. So I will have to look for another solution. Thanks.