# Repeated Multiple Function Calling with 'nested' functions in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a function in `VB.NET` that is inside another function. The outer function is being called with a `BackgroundWorker`. However, when I run the `BackgroundWorker`, the inner function inside an outer function is not running. The `BackgroundWorker` is also being run quickly with a `timer`. I have a simple example of what I mean here:

In this example, a number is being fetched online and added to a set number and displayed in a `TextBox`.

(Note: This is **not** the actual function and just demonstrates what I mean: The Web file fetching demonstrates a slow process that freezes the UI and the second function and the calculation part demonstrates "A function inside another function".).

Outer Function:

```
Public Shared Function FetchUrlContents(inURL As String)

Dim address As String = inURL
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))
TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd

AddNumbers(reader.ReadToEnd)

Return True
End Function
```

Inner Function:

```
Public Shared Function AddNumbers(num As Integer)
TextBox2.Text = 13 + num
End Function
```

These sets of functions works perfectly fine when being called with a control within the UI thread (such as `Buttons` and Form Load events) but partially or do not work when being called **repeatedly** in a `BackgroundWorker`.

For example if I have a `BackgroundWorker` with this:

```
Private Sub webFetcher_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles webFetcher.DoWork

FetchUrlContents("http://example.com/somenumber.txt")

End Sub
```

and I call the `BackgroundWorker` repeatedly like this (with a timer):

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
webFetcher.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

I either get one of two errors. The first error I get is that the `BackgroundWorker` is currently busy:

> The BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently.

which makes sense because it may take longer then a timer tick to fetch a web input.

The second problem I encounter is that the `BackgroundWorker` only runs the contents inside the first function (for example, fetching the text file online and updating the `TextBox1`) but does NOT run the function inside the first function at all. (The `AddNumbers` function).

I know that putting all functions and rewriting them is not a good idea to fit them into the `BackgroundWorker` (since I have a lot of them). How can I fix this so I can correct the above two problems?

Also if it is worth noting, currently `WorkerSupportsCancellation` and `WorkerReportsProgress` are both set to `false`.

Comment: You shouldn't interact with GUI controls in a non-UI thread.

Comment: @LarsTech I have to and its going to slow the UI down if I interact with it in a UI thread. Also, I don't think it causes any problems at the moment

Comment: I didn't say not to use a thread, but you can't interact with `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` like you are in your code without invoking those lines to the GUI thread.

Comment: I believe I used ``System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`` and it worked fine for me

Comment: See [Is it safe just to set CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false to avoid cross threading errors during debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13345091/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech, OK, got it, but would you know how to repeatedly run a ``BackgroundWorker`` with a timer without it being busy? I've seen someone say to create a seperate backgroundworker but I don't think thats a good idea.

Comment: Guess it depends on how often the timer is firing.  You can run multiple threads.

Comment: A single `BackgroundWorker` cannot perform multiple tasks at the same time. It's `DoWork` event handler is executed on a `ThreadPool` thread and does one thing at a time. If you want to perform multiple background tasks at the same time then you could create multiple `BackgroundWorkers`, but you really shouldn't. The old-school option would be to use the `ThreadPool` directly yourself but the new option is the TPL (Tasks Parallel Library). That is independent of the `BackgroundWorker` class so you should research it independent of this question.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is ancient history, use newer threading/tasks patterns. `WebClient` should be cached, otherwise it opens a ton of sockets. `StreamReader` should be disposed with `Using`. And calling `ReadToEnd` twice doesn't make sense