# Process.Exited Button Event Exception

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Button1.Enabled = False
  Dim Process1 As New Process
  Process1.StartInfo.FileName = ("data\test.exe")
  Process1.EnableRaisingEvents = True
  AddHandler Process1.Exited, AddressOf OnExit
  Process1.Start()
End Sub
```

```
Sub OnExit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

[image: There is an error]

I try..

```
Sub OnExit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  Procces1.Close()
  Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Still Error

Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you try the first suggestion in the "Troubleshooting tips" box?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, i tried it.. all the suggestions i found are base C# only

Comment: Procces1.SynchronizingObject = Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OnExit is called by a different thread, you have to use the [Control.BeginInvoke Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) to modify `Button1` properties.

You can use this Sub from [this question (Crossthread operation not valid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240702/crossthread-operation-not-valid-vb-net) to control the Enabled state:

```
Private Sub SetControlEnabled(ByVal ctl As Control, ByVal enabled As Boolean)
    If ctl.InvokeRequired Then
        ctl.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of Control, Boolean)(AddressOf SetControlEnabled), ctl, enabled)
    Else
        ctl.Enabled = enabled
    End If
End Sub
```

Updated code:

```
Sub OnExit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    SetControlEnabled(Button1, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: working 100%. You gave me a valuable lesson, thank you very much.
@ÉtienneLaneville